# Duplicate Span Spring Integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud

Request channel is a scatter channel. Sending request to 3 micro services(outbound gateways) . I was expecting different span for different services to track properly. I am using spring sleuth. Used DefaultHeaderMapper to map header. 
My questions are:
1. How span id is generated, where server/client side? Any reference document to study. 
2. How to resolve the issue of duplicate span in spring integration?

Comment: Got some  idea how Sleuth works. If TraceId,SpanId are not passed in header they are generate at server side. So I tried to remove SpanId to from Header. As I am using defaultHttpHeaderMapper, there is a way to exclude header.

Comment: WARN  o.s.i.h.s.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper - Header 'errorChannel' with value ------
 WARN  o.s.i.h.s.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper - Header 'replyChannel' with value ------
 WARN  o.s.i.h.s.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper - Header 'currentSpan' with value '[Trace: 5cd1817fb7f77f47, Span: 0744723df67d9f43, Parent: 5cd1817fb7f77f47, exportable:false]' ------
 WARN  o.s.i.h.s.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper - Header 'X-Current-Span' with value '[Trace: 5cd1817fb7f77f47, Span: 0744723df67d9f43, Parent: 5cd1817fb7f77f47, exportable:false]'

Comment: But I couldn't find the from where X-Current-Span,currentSpan is getting created and set to DeafultHeaderMapper. This again opens another problem: how to remove these Headers and pass X-B3-TraceId only to avoid recreation of trace in server.

Answer (score 1):

The span is generated on the client side when the message is sent. Then it gets propagated when the message arrives. If a message arrived and there were no messaging headers then the span will be created. Everything is written in the documentation (http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/spring-cloud-sleuth.html) so just read the docs. As for the resolution of duplicate spans I have no idea what you are talking about so I guess you need to provide a more detailed description or a sample to replicate the problem.

Comment: > Sending request to 3 micro services

I guess you do that via `PublishSubscribeChannel`. In this case the same message is sent 3 times and, therefore, we have 3 copies of it and it is obvious with the same headers, including `span`. I'm not sure how does it work, but IMO you should consider to use `child span` here, since the same parent message is sent to different downstream branches. Or.. copy-paste the current `span` to a new one for each publish-subscribe branch.

Comment: Yes, publishSubscribe channel is the request channel for all the 3 outbound gateways.

Comment: I have provided more details to my problem, please find the details if you can help

Comment: I guess you would have to create your own `GlobalChannelInterceptor` that is executed before the `TraceChannelInterceptor` and in that interceptor of yours, you would do whatever you want. However, I don't understand what problem you are trying to solve. In a messaging scenario, it is perfectly valid that you're sending a message with the same Span ID to multiple recipients...